# Why can 尸魂界 be read as ソウル・ソサエティ "Soul Society"? Are there other words that can have a different loan word reading?

Tags: words, readings, loanwords, creative-furigana

I am watching the anime "Bleach" with Japanese audio, and I hear them talk about something in the story called the Soul Society.
When I look at the transcript, I see, that 尸魂界 is used. Curious about the pronunciation, I hear/see the translation in [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E5%B0%B8%E9%AD%82%E7%95%8C&op=translate) romanized as ソウル・ソサエティ (Soul Society). I also see in the [Bleach wiki](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Soul_Society) referred to in the same way.

Has Google Translate been trained to just accept that reading? But it also doesn't make sense to me why the Japanese audio says a different, romanized reading from usual combinations of kunyomi/onyomi. It is not clear to me if there are multiple valid readings of this word.

Are there other words like this, or is this type of thing usually only done for audio/video media? Is there a name for this type of pattern?

Comment: "*Has Google Translate been trained to just accept that reading?*" note that besides their own translation training data, [Google Translate is also crowdsourced](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534530). Users can suggest an edit and others can approve/reject it (resulting in [such case](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/33792/2516)). That said, it's quite common in the literature to [use different readings for kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-furigana).

Comment: There is a tag [creative-furigana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-furigana), where you can find similar examples though not restricted to loan words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

尸魂界 is a made-up word that is used only in Bleach, and its reading, ソウル・ソサエティ, is also completely unique to Bleach. (See [this tag info](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/creative-furigana/info) of [creative-furigana](/questions/tagged/creative-furigana)).

Since this is a popular title that has been around for decades, Google Translate and similar services *may* recognize the term along with its special reading. However, since it's still a unique term used in only one title, it's not surprising if Google Translate fails to offer the reading that Bleach fans expect. Simply, there are no guarantees when it comes to such unique and nonstandard terms.